# add list item depending on another list

Tags: javascript, php

[image: list item image]

i have two list box for countries and states. when i click on a country for ex. India, the corresponding states appears in the states list. but the same should happen for more than one country. if i select two countries, the states of the both countries should be added in the states list.

javascript code for countries list-

```
$('#pcountries').on('change', function() {
    var country_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php_includes/select_list_pstate.php",
        data: 'country_id=' + country_id,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#pstate").append(result);
        }
    });
});
```

php code-

```
if ($_POST['country_id']) {
    $country_id = $_POST['country_id'];
    if ($country_id != '') {
        $states_result = $db_conx->query('select * from states where countryId=' . $country_id . '');
        $options = "<option value=''>Any</option>";
        while ($row = $states_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $options .= "<option value='" . $row['stateId'] . "'>" . $row['state'] . "</option>";
        }
        echo $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've to use `OR` operator in sql query to fetch from both countries. What you are passing if two countries are selected. Check your console

Comment: How many states a can be placed in the second list?
Maybe you can use a logic based on static JSON that are precompiled by PHP with all elements of second list and place only the states that you need to. without perform a query each time.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Select returns an array you need to use `in` instead of `=` in query like this

```
$states_result = $db_conx->query("select * from states where countryId IN (".implode(',',$country_id ).")";);
```

```js
var selectedValues = $('#multipleSelect').val();
console.log(selectedValues)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="multipleSelect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>Text 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```